# Files take up more space on the disk

Tags: macos, disk, ramdisk

When viewing details of a file using `Finder`, different values are shown for how much space the file occupies. For example, a file takes up 28.8KB of RAM but, 33KB of the disk. Anyone know the explanation?

Comment: How are you measuring the RAM usage?

Comment: What files are we talking here? Executable? Data? When executables are loaded, not all of it are loaded, there is what you call as resident size and virtual size. For data, it depends on how the file is loaded. When using mmap(), parts of the data file is loaded, not the whole file. When data files are buffered, buffers flush its content before loading the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk space is allocated in blocks. Meaning, in multiples of a ["block size"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78802/what-are-the-sector-sizes-on-mac-os-x).

For example, on my system a `1 byte` file is `4096 bytes` on disk.

That's `1 byte` of content & `4095 bytes` of unused space.